# Facebook SDK Cocoapod isn't a framework?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods

I'm new to using Facebook & ios development, so I apologize if this is a really stupid question:

Aren't libraries used in iOS development usually in the form of .framework? Why are FBSDK libraries from Cocoapods just a directory full of .h's and .m's? Is there a way for me to convert them into a framework?

I'm using something called the Intel Multi-OS-Engine to enable iOS development using Java, and for it to generate bindings to third-party libraries, they must be in the form of .framework...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download latest from [here](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-ios-sdk-current.zip)

For more information look at quickstart 
guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

Comment: Yes, but I'm already using cocoapods for another library, so I'd prefer to also use cocoapods for Facebook. Is there a reason why the Facebook cocoapods aren't also in .framework form? Thanks

Comment: Did you check under Pods -> Products ? There should be .framework. I'm using https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift...

Comment: I don't even have a Products directory... I'm just really confused why running 'pod install' gives me a directory full of .h, .m, and sometimes .swift files...

Comment: Did you Clean & Build the project. These file you see are public source files. When you build project the .framework will be built. Check the build setting -> search framework paths for location.